How to use Lipschitz continuity to prove existence and uniqueness of initial value problems
I think I understand the definition of Lipschitz continuity for a function of one variable. That is $f(x)$ is said to be Lipschitz continuous in a region $\Omega$ when $\exists L$ such that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x-y|, \quad \forall x,y \in \Omega
$$
A common way to find such $L$ is to use the mean value theorem.
I know that it can be used to prove that an IVP has a unique solution. The Picard–Lindelöf states that given an IVP
$$
\frac{du(t)}{dt} = f(u(t), t) \\
u(t_o)=u_0
$$
If $f(u(t), t)$ is Lipschitz, i.e. $\exists L$ such that
$$
|f(u(t), t) - f(u^{*}(t), t)|\leq|f(u(t) - f(u^{*}(t))|, \quad \forall (u,t),(u^{*}, t) \in \Omega
$$
the IVP has a unique solution.

How can $u(t)$ "vary" if $t$ is fixed? Does this definition mean this inequality must be true for every function of one variable $u^{*}(t)$ defined in $\Omega$.
How can I use this to prove the uniqueness of the solution of
$$
\frac{du(t)}{dt} = u(t)t\\
u(0) = 1
$$

If I try to use the mean value theorem I get
$$
\frac{f(u(t), t) - f(u^{*}(t), t))}{u(t) - u^{*}(t)} = \frac{\partial f(c, t)}{\partial u}
$$
but that means I have to take a derivative with respect to a function. I don't know if that is possible or well defined.

How can I interpret this inequality (when the first parameter is a function itself)?


The theorem of Picard-Lindelöf grants you unique existence of a solution to a given initial value problem on a neighborhood of your initial value, if the function of your differential equation is (locally) Lipschitz-continuous. It seems as if your questions root in a misunderstanding concerning the function $f$ of your differential equation and its domain.
Let's look at the Picard-Lindelöf theorem for clarification:
Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open sets and $f \in C^{0,1-}(I\times\Omega, \mathbb R^n)$. Let $(t_0, u_0) \in I\times\Omega$ and let $a\gt0$ and $r\gt0$, so that $R := [t_0-a, t_0+a] \times \overline B_r(u_0) \subseteq I\times\Omega$. Define $M:=max\{\,\lVert f(t,u) \rVert_{\mathbb R^n} \, | \, (t,u) \in R  \}$ and $\alpha := min \{ a, \frac rM \}$. Then the IVP $$
\begin{cases}
      u'(t) = f(t,u(t))\\
      u(t_0) = u_0& \\
    \end{cases}
$$ has a unique solution on the interval $[t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha] \subseteq I$ with values in $\overline B_r(u_0)$.
As you see $f$ is required to be in $C^{0,1-}(I\times\Omega, \mathbb R^n) := \{f:I\times\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n : f\in C(I\times\Omega, \mathbb R^n) \:\:  \land \:\: f\: is  \: (locally)\:Lipschitz-continuous \ w.r.t. \ u \in \Omega \}.$
A function $f$ is called (locally) Lipschitz-continuous with respect to $u \in \Omega\:$ if for all $(\ \widetilde{t}, \widetilde{u}\ ) \in I\times\Omega$ there exists a neighbourhood $A \times B \subseteq I \times \Omega$, so that there exists $L_{A\times B}\ge0$, so that $\,\lVert f(t,u) - f(t,u^*) \rVert_{\mathbb R^n} \leq L_{A\times B} \vert u - u^* \vert$ for all $u,u^* \in B$ , $t \in A$.
This especially means that $f$, in this role, is a function of two variables in opposition to your conception of $f$ as a function only of one variable $t$ $\:[(f:I \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n,\:t \longrightarrow f(t,u(t))) \neq (f:I \times \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n, \: (t,u) \longrightarrow f(t,u))]$. Instead consider $t\in I$ (like you did) as the variable that likewise will act as the input to your solution $u:I\longrightarrow\mathbb R,\: t \longrightarrow u(t)$ and the variable (!) u $\in \Omega$ as a variable, that acts independent of $t$, in the subset $\Omega$ of your solution's range.
This apprehension of $f$ should resolve the questions (1) and (3).
Now to your question (2): Given the IVP $$
\begin{cases}
      \frac{du(t)}{dt} = u(t) \cdot t\\
      u(0) = 1& \\
    \end{cases}
$$ we  receive our function $f$ as $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R, \: (t,u) \longrightarrow u \cdot t $ (I picked $\:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R\:$ as the domain as $\:(t,u) \longrightarrow u \cdot t\:$ in both arguments is well-defined there and $(t_0,u_0) := (0,1) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R\:$). Now we want to verify that $f$ is (locally) Lipschitz-continuous.
Therefore we derive $f$ with respect to $u$ and see that $\vert \frac{\partial f(t,u)}{\partial u} \vert = \vert t\vert $ combined with the Mean Value Theorem is sufficient to show local Lipschitz-continuity. At last we apply Picard-Lindelöf and obtain the existence of a unique solution $\:\: u: [-\frac 12, \frac 12] \longrightarrow \overline B_{1}(1) \:\: $ (after arbitrarily choosing $a=1$ and $r=1$).
I hope this answers your questions!
